# Changing the value of an array of objects based on another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays.

```
let arr1 = [{id: 1, favorite: false}, {id: 2, favorite: false}, {id: 3, favorite: false}];
let arr2 = [1, 3];
```

If the id exists in `arr2`, I want to change the `favorite` to `true` (of that particular object)

For example. in the above case, the final `arr1` would look like

```
[{id: 1, favorite: true}, {id: 2, favorite: false}, {id: 3, favorite: true}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.map` to iterate over `arr1` and `.includes` to check if the item's `id` is in `arr2`:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id: 1, favorite: false}, 
  {id: 2, favorite: false}, 
  {id: 3, favorite: false}
];
const arr2 = [1, 3];

const res = arr1.map(e => 
  ({...e, favorite: arr2.includes(e.id)})
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @rohanharikr you are welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution to close the question

Answer (score 2):

You can also use  `some` method like:

```js
const newArr = arr1.map(item =>  { return { ...item, favorite: arr2.some(elem => elem === item.id) } })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `forEach` and `includes`.

```js
let arr1 = [{id: 1, favorite: false}, {id: 2, favorite: false}, {id: 3, favorite: false}];
let arr2 = [1, 3];

arr1.forEach(x => x.favorite = arr2.includes(x.id))

console.log(arr1);
```